# Choosing bach size and learning rate for large datastet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, data-science

The dataset has around 2.5 million rows, and I'm using a 80/20 train test split.
I read some answers here and some papers regarding this which suggest batch sizes of 32 or 64. But wouldn't that be extremely small relative to the size of the dataset?
I previously trained with a bath size of10000 and LR of 1e-2 but did not get a good accuracy.

What values would be optimal for a dataset this large?

Comment: LR and other hyper-parameters depend on data, so we can not tell what would be the optimal values unless we have the data and inspect it. Also you should determine the batch size considering your computation power.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which framework do you use. TensorFlow, for example, has a callback like [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau). It reduces learning rate when the metric has stopped improving. The main parameter is factor - factor by which the learning rate will be reduced: `lr = lr * factor`.

By using ReduceLROnPlateau, you can start with a relatively high learning rate, which will be automatically reduced by the callback.

```
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.3, 
                              patience=3, min_lr=0.0001)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```